# Speical character handle in lua nginx

Tags: regex, parsing, nginx, lua

I want to print ab"c but it is causing problem. I parsed it but still i am seeing the issue.

```
location /test {
content_by_lua '
       local str = "ab\"c"
ngx.print(str)
';
}
```

Comment: Try `local str = "ab"..string.char(34).."c"`

Comment: Probably nginx unescapes backslashed symbols prior to running Lua script.  Try to double all backslashes `local str = "ab\\"c"`

Comment: No, this question is not a duplicate of the linked one.

Comment: thanks @EgorSkriptunoff this is not a duplicate. any way fine